# Allow invoice for selected customers

Tags: magento2, invoice

I'm looking for an extension that allows my customers to receive an automated invoice based on their order.
Also, only a selected number of customers should have this option.

Comment: So you want specific customer based on email or customer group to receive invoice? Also by receive invoice you mean receive email with attachment?

Comment: The customers are already registered in my Magento 2 store, but I want some of them to be Invoice enabled, since they are trusted customers. So when they order, they should receive an automatic invoice via email, based on their order. I don't think I can use customer groups for this, as I already have different prices for different customer groups, and it would be to much hassle and redundancy to recreate all prices for this new invoice enabled customer group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of plugins.
First Magedelight Payment Restriction to restrict invoice to certain customers.
Then Magetrend PDF invoice to create a nicer invoice.
Then Fooman Emailattachments to attach the invoice PDF to the invoice email.

Answer (score 1):

I created something

Here you go

https://github.com/DominicWatts/AutoInvoice

Doesn't email.  But the logic generates invoice based on different options.  If the order or customer doesn't meet selected criteria it won't be invoiced.

Comment: This looks great, it looks like it would have been great if I didn't bought the Magedelight payment restriction.